# How to edit the position of floating label in an edittext with icon

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design

I have an editText with a floating label(hint).I have also added an icon to that editText. I want the label to be on the top of the icon but it appears on the top just after the icon.I am using this dependency - 
compile 'com.github.vajro:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.6'

my xml :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.itjobnotification.first.app.signupActivity"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:text="Personal Details"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#d7d7d8"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"/>


                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Name"
                        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/name"
                        android:maxLines="1"/>

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/input_layout_name"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Email"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/card_view_professional"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:contentPadding="10dp">>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/prof">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:text="Professional Details"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#d7d7d8"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_years"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/yearsOfExperience"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Years of Experience"
                        android:maxLines="1"/>

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_ctc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/input_layout_years"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ctc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Current CTC (in LPA)"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/college"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:entries="@array/college"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/input_layout_ctc"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/input_layout_ctc" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/loc"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:entries="@array/location"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/college"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/input_layout_ctc" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_promo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_view_professional"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/promocode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Promo Code (Optional)"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_below="@+id/button"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/terms"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#1E88E5"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chooseSkills"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/card_view_professional"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/card_view" />

        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
            android:id="@+id/chooseSkills"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#1E88E5"
            android:text="Choose skills"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/input_layout_promo"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/card_view" />

    </RelativeLayout>

     </ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you post a screen shot of the problem

Comment: I tried but I couldn't due to less repo.

Answer (score 0):

ok I don't get the issue entirely but I have had an issue with TextInputLayout when I add custom background that the padding were wrong so I ended up adding some extra padding using xml background maybe this will help you then add thia as a background to your edittext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_selector"
    android:top="@dimen/activity_medim_margin">
    <!--<your original background; can be <bitmap> or <shape> or whatever./>-->
</item>
```